# Sharing test cases between specs in protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Right now I have a set of specs that are shared between two different specs in protractor.

What i have done is to write all the test cases inside a pageobject and then call that function from the suite.

Eg: PageObject

```
var testing_helper = function(){


this.functu = function(a,b){
//test case one . without using "it" functions.
//test case two
//testcase three.
...... 
}
```

the suite.js file looks like

```
var x = require('./testing_helper');
describe('description' function(){

  if(some condition){
   it('description', function(){
     x.functu(a,b);
   });
   }

});
```

This runs the test fine but there is no description or separate test cases in the generated report. The report file only shows one test instead of all three.

```
<testsuites disabled="0" errors="0" failures="0" tests="1" time="121.175">
 <testsuite name="This is rbac" timestamp="2018-07-09T14:59:41" hostname="localhost" time="121.175" errors="0" tests="1" skipped="0" disabled="0" failures="0">
  <testcase classname="This is rbac" name="runs the rbac off user" time="121.174" />
 </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I know this is not the right way to do this and it makes it impossible to give descriptions to each functions in the end report.

Is there a way to properly define the "it" specs for spec one, spec two and spec three and then use them in a suite and run them based on conditions?

Comment: Aren't those your functions and not specs? Specs are used for testing. But believe you are putting some resusable functions there and not specs exactly?

Comment: @eduPeeth  I have edited the question is there a way to write common specs and share them between suites other than this?

Comment: I think you shall write common functions and call them in your specs rather than common specs. Common functions make sense than common specs. Isn't it?

Comment: You shall define specs in your test suite and call the required functions in them. That's how my understanding goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be organized like -

```
var testing_helper = function(){       
add = function(a,b){
....
}    
subtract = function(a,b){
....
}    
}
```

Then, defining your test suites -

```
var x = require('./testing_helper');
describe('description' function(){  
   it('description', function(){
      if(some condition){
        x.add(a,b);
      }
   });

   it('description', function(){
      if(some condition){
        x.subtract(a,b);
      }
   });  

});
```

Does that make sense or any limitations if you find?

What I mean is, let's say you have `login` function which is to be used across many specs. You can have it there in helper and call it here in any number of specs you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot will try this and will let you know

Comment: Surely, anytime.

Comment: @SharathPrakash, any time mate :). Glad it works for you.

Comment: Dear sir, I have an issue in this link. Kindly take a look if possible

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265499/variable-scope-in-protractor